# Recognizing an image inside another with a certain acceptance value in opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

If you have ever played the game Set, you might understand better. I have been working on a Python program that finds sets in a given group of cards. I got that part working fairly quickly. I now want to speed up the card input process by allowing the user to take a picture of all the cards and having a program to recognize which cards are visible in the photo using opencv. Say I get pictures of every card in the game (there are 81). How could I go about testing if each card image is **somewhat** visible in the user’s image with opencv?

My image (sorry for the pixelation, I couldn't find a good image):
[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01qjy.png)

User's image
[User's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFHYi.jpg)

I saw an opencv function called matchTemplate, but only seems to search for exact matches where the smaller image was actually taken from the larger one.

Comment: You can use matchTemplate, but the template image must have nearly the same scale and nearly the same rotation as in the larger image. That should work. You should know the size of the region you want to find (cards in the larger image) and scale your template to match that size before using matchTemplate

Comment: **No links to images.** Also include code. You have angered community bot, and now community bot is coming for you... to provide you some good advice ⬇️

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.